# Plot bar chart from imported data from csv

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My current goal is to print a bar chart from CSV file into xlabel"Offices" and ylabel"Count of people".
The problem is I'm not sure how I can calculate how many people are from respective office, which then could be translated to a bar chart with a calculated amount.

Case:

I have created a dummy CSV file, with: FirstName, LastName, DOB, PhoneNumber, Position, Employment, and Office.

Data would look like this:

- Tom, Belington, 1999-01-01, 169874654, Manager, True, LV
- Tom, Belington, 1999-01-01, 169874654, Agent, True, PA
- Tom, Belington, 1999-01-01, 169874654, Agent, True, CA
- Tom, Belington, 1999-01-01, 169874654, Agent, True, LV
- Tom, Belington, 1999-01-01, 169874654, Agent, True, CA
- Tom, Belington, 1999-01-01, 169874654, Agent, True, CA
- Tom, Belington, 1999-01-01, 169874654, Agent, True, PA

I'm currently using pandas and matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use seaborn countplot or use value_counts() and then bar plot if you want to use matplotlib only.

**Seaborn Code**

```
df=pd.read_csv('inputfile.csv')
ax=sns.countplot(data=df, x='Office')
ax.set(xlabel='Offices', ylabel='Count of people')
```

[image]

**Using matplotlib only**

```
df=pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
df.Office.value_counts().plot.bar()
ax.set(xlabel='Offices', ylabel='Count of people')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be more easily done with `sns.countplot`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(df.Office)
```

Another way is to get count per office with `value_counts`:

```
df.Office.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```